# Single command to remove files that have a '3' in them

Tags: bash, command-line, for-loop

Say I have a list of files numbered 1-50 and I want to remove only the ones that have the number '3' in them. How would I do that?

Comment: Be careful not to remove all of your computer's threes. You might need them. Three is an important integer, arguably one of the *most* important. Even people who say that there are more important natural numbers than the underrated three would agree that it's up there pretty high. You might think you can build an oreo with just a two and a one, but I ask you how many layers you end up with? That's right: three. Use caution is all I'm saying. Don't run as root. Don't swap out the swapper. And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for globbing:

```
rm *3*
```

Make sure you check it first with something harmless (like `ls`).

Can't imagine why you would need this though.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

With `find`:

```
find . -name '*3*' -exec rm {} ;\
```

Answer (score -1):

Supposing you actually meant to delete only the files *containing* 3 (as opposed to the other answer about files *named* 3) then you could do:

```
rm `grep -l 3 *`
```

(or replace `*` with whatever matches the set of files you want to consider)

Comment: This will break if the file names contain spaces or newlines

Comment: I should have clarified, I did mean files that were named with 3 in them.